# R/ggplot2 -- facet by day, plotting in the wrong order

Tags: r, datetime, plot, ggplot2, timezone

I am trying to plot some time series data and facet it by day. I have no trouble managing the facets, but cannot understand why the x-axis for each day is not in the right order. That is, instead of starting at 0:00 and ending at 23:59, it's starting at 22:00 and ending at 22:00. Any help greatly appreciated:

[image]

```
#Convert Datetime column to R POSIXct
original_data$Date<-as.POSIXct(x = original_data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

#Set reference values to numeric
original_data$Reference<-as.numeric(original_data$Reference)

calibration_plot<-ggplot(original_data, aes(Date, Reference)) +
facet_wrap(~DOY, scales = "free") + xlab("Time (hours)") + 
geom_point()+     ylab(expression(Radiation ~ (W ~ m^{-2}))) + 
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H")) + ggtitle("Calibration 
Plots") + theme_bw() + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12), 
axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"), title = 
element_text(size=10, face = "bold"))


Date    DOY Reference
11/7/2016 0:01  312 -0.0137
11/7/2016 0:06  312 -0.01525
11/7/2016 0:11  312 -0.01325
11/7/2016 0:16  312 -0.01235
11/7/2016 0:21  312 -0.0119
11/7/2016 0:26  312 -0.0112
11/7/2016 0:31  312 -0.0109
11/7/2016 0:36  312 -0.0112
11/7/2016 0:41  312 -0.0105
11/7/2016 0:46  312 -0.00865
11/7/2016 0:51  312 -0.00875
11/7/2016 0:56  312 -0.0081
11/7/2016 1:01  312 -0.00885
11/7/2016 1:06  312 -0.00775
11/7/2016 1:11  312 -0.0086
11/7/2016 1:16  312 -0.0085
11/7/2016 1:21  312 -0.00915
11/7/2016 1:26  312 -0.0077
11/7/2016 1:31  312 -0.0114
11/7/2016 1:36  312 -0.0148
11/7/2016 1:41  312 -0.0121
11/7/2016 1:46  312 -0.012
11/7/2016 1:51  312 -0.0121
11/7/2016 1:56  312 -0.0086
11/7/2016 2:01  312 -0.00915
11/7/2016 2:06  312 -0.00945
11/7/2016 2:11  312 -0.0072
11/7/2016 2:16  312 -0.00485
11/7/2016 2:21  312 -0.006
11/7/2016 2:26  312 -0.00605
11/7/2016 2:31  312 -0.00685
11/7/2016 2:36  312 -0.00905
11/7/2016 2:41  312 -0.01085
11/7/2016 2:46  312 -0.0133
11/7/2016 2:51  312 -0.0118
11/7/2016 2:56  312 -0.01285
11/7/2016 3:01  312 -0.0125
11/7/2016 3:06  312 -0.0108
11/7/2016 3:11  312 -0.0114
11/7/2016 3:16  312 -0.01165
11/7/2016 3:21  312 -0.0117
11/7/2016 3:26  312 -0.0116
11/7/2016 3:31  312 -0.01155
11/7/2016 3:36  312 -0.01345
11/7/2016 3:41  312 -0.01375
11/7/2016 3:46  312 -0.01405
11/7/2016 3:51  312 -0.01195
11/7/2016 3:56  312 -0.012
11/7/2016 4:01  312 -0.0115
11/7/2016 4:06  312 -0.01215
11/7/2016 4:11  312 -0.01155
11/7/2016 4:16  312 -0.013
11/7/2016 4:21  312 -0.01135
11/7/2016 4:26  312 -0.01165
11/7/2016 4:31  312 -0.01125
11/7/2016 4:36  312 -0.01025
11/7/2016 4:41  312 -0.0106
11/7/2016 4:46  312 -0.0118
11/7/2016 4:51  312 -0.01045
11/7/2016 4:56  312 -0.0108
11/7/2016 5:01  312 -0.01315
11/7/2016 5:06  312 -0.01155
11/7/2016 5:11  312 -0.01195
11/7/2016 5:16  312 -0.01255
11/7/2016 5:21  312 -0.01145
11/7/2016 5:26  312 -0.011
11/7/2016 5:31  312 -0.0108
11/7/2016 5:36  312 -0.01115
11/7/2016 5:41  312 -0.0104
11/7/2016 5:46  312 -0.00325
11/7/2016 5:51  312 0.01585
11/7/2016 5:56  312 0.0383
11/7/2016 6:01  312 0.0541
11/7/2016 6:06  312 0.08845
11/7/2016 6:11  312 0.16495
11/7/2016 6:16  312 0.2525
11/7/2016 6:21  312 0.3453
11/7/2016 6:26  312 0.4411
11/7/2016 6:31  312 0.5581
11/7/2016 6:36  312 0.73945
11/7/2016 6:41  312 0.84045
11/7/2016 6:46  312 1.0619
11/7/2016 6:51  312 1.50535
11/7/2016 6:56  312 1.7774
11/7/2016 7:01  312 1.9699
11/7/2016 7:06  312 1.94915
11/7/2016 7:11  312 1.984
11/7/2016 7:16  312 2.17855
11/7/2016 7:21  312 2.5005
11/7/2016 7:26  312 2.35345
11/7/2016 7:31  312 2.43305
11/7/2016 7:36  312 2.63425
11/7/2016 7:41  312 3.16065
11/7/2016 7:46  312 3.34475
11/7/2016 7:51  312 3.2605
11/7/2016 7:56  312 3.3372
11/7/2016 8:01  312 3.3398
11/7/2016 8:06  312 3.43235
11/7/2016 8:11  312 3.8922
11/7/2016 8:16  312 4.359
11/7/2016 8:21  312 4.4112
11/7/2016 8:26  312 4.7168
11/7/2016 8:31  312 4.8878
11/7/2016 8:36  312 5.05045
11/7/2016 8:41  312 5.20745
11/7/2016 8:46  312 4.82285
11/7/2016 8:51  312 5.19705
11/7/2016 8:56  312 4.9623
11/7/2016 9:01  312 5.164
11/7/2016 9:06  312 5.85755
11/7/2016 9:11  312 5.91635
11/7/2016 9:16  312 6.20635
11/7/2016 9:21  312 6.3367
11/7/2016 9:26  312 6.4511
11/7/2016 9:31  312 6.5009
11/7/2016 9:36  312 6.55115
11/7/2016 9:41  312 6.77255
11/7/2016 9:46  312 6.73385
11/7/2016 9:51  312 6.739
11/7/2016 9:56  312 7.0979
11/7/2016 10:01 312 7.2608
11/7/2016 10:06 312 7.39525
11/7/2016 10:11 312 7.32865
11/7/2016 10:16 312 7.4016
11/7/2016 10:21 312 7.70725
11/7/2016 10:26 312 7.8645
11/7/2016 10:31 312 7.8682
11/7/2016 10:36 312 8.0161
11/7/2016 10:41 312 7.7934
11/7/2016 10:46 312 5.99495
11/7/2016 10:51 312 8.25685
11/7/2016 10:56 312 8.7265
11/7/2016 11:01 312 8.5505
11/7/2016 11:06 312 8.1372
11/7/2016 11:11 312 5.0642
11/7/2016 11:16 312 5.0355
11/7/2016 11:21 312 6.32535
11/7/2016 11:26 312 5.8676
11/7/2016 11:31 312 7.37175
11/7/2016 11:36 312 6.1949
11/7/2016 11:41 312 5.01225
11/7/2016 11:46 312 5.91725
11/7/2016 11:51 312 6.7572
11/7/2016 11:56 312 7.70375
11/7/2016 12:01 312 8.12815
11/7/2016 12:06 312 6.04805
11/7/2016 12:11 312 5.2638
11/7/2016 12:16 312 4.85
11/7/2016 12:21 312 4.2291
11/7/2016 12:26 312 4.2851
11/7/2016 12:31 312 4.99735
11/7/2016 12:36 312 4.7308
11/7/2016 12:41 312 5.2383
11/7/2016 12:46 312 6.9894
11/7/2016 12:51 312 6.8357
11/7/2016 12:56 312 9.124
11/7/2016 13:01 312 9.2875
11/7/2016 13:06 312 7.11615
11/7/2016 13:11 312 7.8034
11/7/2016 13:16 312 5.29235
11/7/2016 13:21 312 6.02785
11/7/2016 13:26 312 5.6154
11/7/2016 13:31 312 3.5963
11/7/2016 13:36 312 2.88325
11/7/2016 13:41 312 2.7976
11/7/2016 13:46 312 3.07845
11/7/2016 13:51 312 3.55455
11/7/2016 13:56 312 3.2716
11/7/2016 14:01 312 2.8856
11/7/2016 14:06 312 4.42685
11/7/2016 14:11 312 6.93045
11/7/2016 14:16 312 6.68565
11/7/2016 14:21 312 6.0181
11/7/2016 14:26 312 3.3964
11/7/2016 14:31 312 3.3697
11/7/2016 14:36 312 2.99275
11/7/2016 14:41 312 5.2926
11/7/2016 14:46 312 4.70665
11/7/2016 14:51 312 4.16065
11/7/2016 14:56 312 3.7451
11/7/2016 15:01 312 3.47665
11/7/2016 15:06 312 3.2893
11/7/2016 15:11 312 3.0863
11/7/2016 15:16 312 2.9122
11/7/2016 15:21 312 2.71525
11/7/2016 15:26 312 2.50645
11/7/2016 15:31 312 2.26005
11/7/2016 15:36 312 2.0562
11/7/2016 15:41 312 1.89285
11/7/2016 15:46 312 1.3635
11/7/2016 15:51 312 1.1739
11/7/2016 15:56 312 1.4291
11/7/2016 16:01 312 1.1776
11/7/2016 16:06 312 1.03155
11/7/2016 16:11 312 0.8916
11/7/2016 16:16 312 0.73225
11/7/2016 16:21 312 0.6009
11/7/2016 16:26 312 0.47795
11/7/2016 16:31 312 0.35235
11/7/2016 16:36 312 0.2142
11/7/2016 16:41 312 0.11565
11/7/2016 16:46 312 0.04355
11/7/2016 16:51 312 0.0127
11/7/2016 16:56 312 -0.00405
11/7/2016 17:01 312 -0.0198
11/7/2016 17:06 312 -0.02375
11/7/2016 17:11 312 -0.0219
11/7/2016 17:16 312 -0.01975
11/7/2016 17:21 312 -0.02105
11/7/2016 17:26 312 -0.02275
11/7/2016 17:31 312 -0.022
11/7/2016 17:36 312 -0.02135
11/7/2016 17:41 312 -0.02165
11/7/2016 17:46 312 -0.0232
11/7/2016 17:51 312 -0.01995
11/7/2016 17:56 312 -0.02085
11/7/2016 18:01 312 -0.0197
11/7/2016 18:06 312 -0.02185
11/7/2016 18:11 312 -0.0213
11/7/2016 18:16 312 -0.022
11/7/2016 18:21 312 -0.01915
11/7/2016 18:26 312 -0.0211
11/7/2016 18:31 312 -0.02025
11/7/2016 18:36 312 -0.0198
11/7/2016 18:41 312 -0.0205
11/7/2016 18:46 312 -0.0212
11/7/2016 18:51 312 -0.0212
11/7/2016 18:56 312 -0.0221
11/7/2016 19:01 312 -0.0209
11/7/2016 19:06 312 -0.0214
11/7/2016 19:11 312 -0.02025
11/7/2016 19:16 312 -0.02115
11/7/2016 19:21 312 -0.02205
11/7/2016 19:26 312 -0.0225
11/7/2016 19:31 312 -0.0216
11/7/2016 19:36 312 -0.0206
11/7/2016 19:41 312 -0.02145
11/7/2016 19:46 312 -0.0214
11/7/2016 19:51 312 -0.02115
11/7/2016 19:56 312 -0.021
11/7/2016 20:01 312 -0.02075
11/7/2016 20:06 312 -0.0224
11/7/2016 20:11 312 -0.02035
11/7/2016 20:16 312 -0.01915
11/7/2016 20:21 312 -0.02075
11/7/2016 20:26 312 -0.02095
11/7/2016 20:31 312 -0.0228
11/7/2016 20:36 312 -0.0207
11/7/2016 20:41 312 -0.0215
11/7/2016 20:46 312 -0.01995
11/7/2016 20:51 312 -0.0209
11/7/2016 20:56 312 -0.0202
11/7/2016 21:01 312 -0.02125
11/7/2016 21:06 312 -0.02045
11/7/2016 21:11 312 -0.02345
11/7/2016 21:16 312 -0.02325
11/7/2016 21:21 312 -0.02195
11/7/2016 21:26 312 -0.02065
11/7/2016 21:31 312 -0.01935
11/7/2016 21:36 312 -0.01475
11/7/2016 21:41 312 -0.0172
11/7/2016 21:46 312 -0.01635
11/7/2016 21:51 312 -0.01495
11/7/2016 21:56 312 -0.0145
11/7/2016 22:01 312 -0.0177
11/7/2016 22:06 312 -0.01585
11/7/2016 22:11 312 -0.0134
11/7/2016 22:16 312 -0.01355
11/7/2016 22:21 312 -0.01435
11/7/2016 22:26 312 -0.0134
11/7/2016 22:31 312 -0.0157
11/7/2016 22:36 312 -0.01535
11/7/2016 22:41 312 -0.0139
11/7/2016 22:46 312 -0.01495
11/7/2016 22:51 312 -0.01585
11/7/2016 22:56 312 -0.01735
11/7/2016 23:01 312 -0.01475
11/7/2016 23:06 312 -0.0165
11/7/2016 23:11 312 -0.0157
11/7/2016 23:16 312 -0.0223
11/7/2016 23:21 312 -0.0214
11/7/2016 23:26 312 -0.02155
11/7/2016 23:31 312 -0.02245
11/7/2016 23:36 312 -0.0223
11/7/2016 23:41 312 -0.02315
11/7/2016 23:46 312 -0.0204
11/7/2016 23:51 312 -0.01915
11/7/2016 23:56 312 -0.018
11/8/2016 0:01  313 -0.01895
11/8/2016 0:06  313 -0.0195
11/8/2016 0:11  313 -0.0152
11/8/2016 0:16  313 -0.0157
11/8/2016 0:21  313 -0.0177
11/8/2016 0:26  313 -0.0179
11/8/2016 0:31  313 -0.0185
11/8/2016 0:36  313 -0.0164
11/8/2016 0:41  313 -0.0145
11/8/2016 0:46  313 -0.0158
11/8/2016 0:51  313 -0.01295
11/8/2016 0:56  313 -0.0149
11/8/2016 1:01  313 -0.014
11/8/2016 1:06  313 -0.01505
11/8/2016 1:11  313 -0.01795
11/8/2016 1:16  313 -0.01375
11/8/2016 1:21  313 -0.0066
11/8/2016 1:26  313 -0.00835
11/8/2016 1:31  313 -0.00785
11/8/2016 1:36  313 -0.0082
11/8/2016 1:41  313 -0.0108
11/8/2016 1:46  313 -0.01275
11/8/2016 1:51  313 -0.01515
11/8/2016 1:56  313 -0.01505
11/8/2016 2:01  313 -0.01805
11/8/2016 2:06  313 -0.01875
11/8/2016 2:11  313 -0.01955
11/8/2016 2:16  313 -0.0201
11/8/2016 2:21  313 -0.0183
11/8/2016 2:26  313 -0.01715
11/8/2016 2:31  313 -0.0169
11/8/2016 2:36  313 -0.0139
11/8/2016 2:41  313 -0.0145
11/8/2016 2:46  313 -0.0162
11/8/2016 2:51  313 -0.01275
11/8/2016 2:56  313 -0.01285
11/8/2016 3:01  313 -0.01605
11/8/2016 3:06  313 -0.0133
11/8/2016 3:11  313 -0.00905
11/8/2016 3:16  313 -0.0149
11/8/2016 3:21  313 -0.01395
11/8/2016 3:26  313 -0.01115
11/8/2016 3:31  313 -0.0108
11/8/2016 3:36  313 -0.01015
11/8/2016 3:41  313 -0.00805
11/8/2016 3:46  313 -0.00735
11/8/2016 3:51  313 -0.00615
11/8/2016 3:56  313 -0.0055
11/8/2016 4:01  313 -0.0138
11/8/2016 4:06  313 -0.01405
11/8/2016 4:11  313 -0.01755
11/8/2016 4:16  313 -0.0181
11/8/2016 4:21  313 -0.01675
11/8/2016 4:26  313 -0.0165
11/8/2016 4:31  313 -0.01455
11/8/2016 4:36  313 -0.01425
11/8/2016 4:41  313 -0.0146
11/8/2016 4:46  313 -0.0152
11/8/2016 4:51  313 -0.0125
11/8/2016 4:56  313 -0.0117
11/8/2016 5:01  313 -0.01215
11/8/2016 5:06  313 -0.0125
11/8/2016 5:11  313 -0.0132
11/8/2016 5:16  313 -0.0126
11/8/2016 5:21  313 -0.0135
11/8/2016 5:26  313 -0.01165
11/8/2016 5:31  313 -0.00775
11/8/2016 5:36  313 -0.00695
11/8/2016 5:41  313 -0.00385
11/8/2016 5:46  313 -0.00235
11/8/2016 5:51  313 0.0028
11/8/2016 5:56  313 0.01585
11/8/2016 6:01  313 0.03635
11/8/2016 6:06  313 0.07065
11/8/2016 6:11  313 0.1311
11/8/2016 6:16  313 0.21305
11/8/2016 6:21  313 0.32055
11/8/2016 6:26  313 0.43565
11/8/2016 6:31  313 0.5715
11/8/2016 6:36  313 0.7204
11/8/2016 6:41  313 0.8756
11/8/2016 6:46  313 1.0433
11/8/2016 6:51  313 1.2124
11/8/2016 6:56  313 1.3829
11/8/2016 7:01  313 1.5636
11/8/2016 7:06  313 1.7513
11/8/2016 7:11  313 1.9341
11/8/2016 7:16  313 2.11025
11/8/2016 7:21  313 2.28195
11/8/2016 7:26  313 2.46095
11/8/2016 7:31  313 2.64895
11/8/2016 7:36  313 2.83475
11/8/2016 7:41  313 3.01725
11/8/2016 7:46  313 3.19545
11/8/2016 7:51  313 3.37045
11/8/2016 7:56  313 3.5479
11/8/2016 8:01  313 3.71555
11/8/2016 8:06  313 3.89685
11/8/2016 8:11  313 4.0722
11/8/2016 8:16  313 4.24365
11/8/2016 8:21  313 4.421
11/8/2016 8:26  313 4.6007
11/8/2016 8:31  313 4.7579
11/8/2016 8:36  313 4.9085
11/8/2016 8:41  313 5.0742
11/8/2016 8:46  313 5.2702
11/8/2016 8:51  313 5.43175
11/8/2016 8:56  313 5.5679
11/8/2016 9:01  313 5.70595
11/8/2016 9:06  313 5.8536
11/8/2016 9:11  313 6.00405
11/8/2016 9:16  313 6.14975
11/8/2016 9:21  313 6.28225
11/8/2016 9:26  313 6.3957
11/8/2016 9:31  313 6.49145
11/8/2016 9:36  313 6.61005
11/8/2016 9:41  313 6.7059
11/8/2016 9:46  313 6.803
11/8/2016 9:51  313 6.9047
11/8/2016 9:56  313 6.99005
11/8/2016 10:01 313 7.10665
11/8/2016 10:06 313 7.1775
11/8/2016 10:11 313 7.24965
11/8/2016 10:16 313 7.32285
11/8/2016 10:21 313 7.40145
11/8/2016 10:26 313 7.4465
11/8/2016 10:31 313 7.48625
11/8/2016 10:36 313 7.5403
11/8/2016 10:41 313 7.56665
11/8/2016 10:46 313 7.6129
11/8/2016 10:51 313 7.6587
11/8/2016 10:56 313 7.65805
11/8/2016 11:01 313 7.69065
11/8/2016 11:06 313 7.69305
11/8/2016 11:11 313 7.75695
11/8/2016 11:16 313 7.7813
11/8/2016 11:21 313 7.807
11/8/2016 11:26 313 7.84605
11/8/2016 11:31 313 7.86405
11/8/2016 11:36 313 7.86835
11/8/2016 11:41 313 7.71245
11/8/2016 11:46 313 7.81435
11/8/2016 11:51 313 7.78805
11/8/2016 11:56 313 7.7583
11/8/2016 12:01 313 7.70065
11/8/2016 12:06 313 7.6603
11/8/2016 12:11 313 7.622
11/8/2016 12:16 313 7.56315
11/8/2016 12:21 313 7.4049
11/8/2016 12:26 313 7.4034
11/8/2016 12:31 313 7.278
11/8/2016 12:36 313 7.3192
11/8/2016 12:41 313 7.19265
11/8/2016 12:46 313 7.4927
11/8/2016 12:51 313 7.54555
11/8/2016 12:56 313 7.69435
11/8/2016 13:01 313 6.95105
11/8/2016 13:06 313 6.26065
11/8/2016 13:11 313 6.90735
11/8/2016 13:16 313 6.4603
11/8/2016 13:21 313 5.69755
11/8/2016 13:26 313 5.30295
11/8/2016 13:31 313 5.993
11/8/2016 13:36 313 6.24425
11/8/2016 13:41 313 5.89575
11/8/2016 13:46 313 6.3803
11/8/2016 13:51 313 6.17455
11/8/2016 13:56 313 5.6555
11/8/2016 14:01 313 5.0811
11/8/2016 14:06 313 3.33805
11/8/2016 14:11 313 3.131
11/8/2016 14:16 313 3.87235
11/8/2016 14:21 313 4.3724
11/8/2016 14:26 313 4.6554
11/8/2016 14:31 313 4.7956
11/8/2016 14:36 313 3.41335
11/8/2016 14:41 313 3.11155
11/8/2016 14:46 313 3.9269
11/8/2016 14:51 313 2.8726
11/8/2016 14:56 313 2.68095
11/8/2016 15:01 313 2.98235
11/8/2016 15:06 313 3.1635
11/8/2016 15:11 313 3.09815
11/8/2016 15:16 313 2.89455
11/8/2016 15:21 313 2.7253
11/8/2016 15:26 313 2.52735
11/8/2016 15:31 313 2.30685
11/8/2016 15:36 313 1.9471
11/8/2016 15:41 313 1.76245
11/8/2016 15:46 313 1.7001
11/8/2016 15:51 313 1.509
11/8/2016 15:56 313 1.31435
11/8/2016 16:01 313 1.1337
11/8/2016 16:06 313 0.9801
11/8/2016 16:11 313 0.83105
11/8/2016 16:16 313 0.67265
11/8/2016 16:21 313 0.53225
11/8/2016 16:26 313 0.41065
11/8/2016 16:31 313 0.3211
11/8/2016 16:36 313 0.2437
11/8/2016 16:41 313 0.1663
11/8/2016 16:46 313 0.08585
11/8/2016 16:51 313 0.02745
11/8/2016 16:56 313 -0.001
11/8/2016 17:01 313 -0.0124
11/8/2016 17:06 313 -0.01965
11/8/2016 17:11 313 -0.0209
11/8/2016 17:16 313 -0.0219
11/8/2016 17:21 313 -0.02165
11/8/2016 17:26 313 -0.0221
11/8/2016 17:31 313 -0.021
11/8/2016 17:36 313 -0.02155
11/8/2016 17:41 313 -0.0211
11/8/2016 17:46 313 -0.0214
11/8/2016 17:51 313 -0.0222
11/8/2016 17:56 313 -0.0209
11/8/2016 18:01 313 -0.0217
11/8/2016 18:06 313 -0.0225
11/8/2016 18:11 313 -0.0215
11/8/2016 18:16 313 -0.02195
11/8/2016 18:21 313 -0.0217
11/8/2016 18:26 313 -0.02125
11/8/2016 18:31 313 -0.02095
11/8/2016 18:36 313 -0.0218
11/8/2016 18:41 313 -0.02165
11/8/2016 18:46 313 -0.02235
11/8/2016 18:51 313 -0.0214
11/8/2016 18:56 313 -0.0211
11/8/2016 19:01 313 -0.02195
11/8/2016 19:06 313 -0.02135
11/8/2016 19:11 313 -0.02195
11/8/2016 19:16 313 -0.0222
11/8/2016 19:21 313 -0.0215
11/8/2016 19:26 313 -0.02155
11/8/2016 19:31 313 -0.0225
11/8/2016 19:36 313 -0.02205
11/8/2016 19:41 313 -0.0209
11/8/2016 19:46 313 -0.0222
11/8/2016 19:51 313 -0.02205
11/8/2016 19:56 313 -0.02255
11/8/2016 20:01 313 -0.0224
11/8/2016 20:06 313 -0.0232
11/8/2016 20:11 313 -0.0234
11/8/2016 20:16 313 -0.02285
11/8/2016 20:21 313 -0.0224
11/8/2016 20:26 313 -0.0242
11/8/2016 20:31 313 -0.023
11/8/2016 20:36 313 -0.02055
11/8/2016 20:41 313 -0.01945
11/8/2016 20:46 313 -0.0173
11/8/2016 20:51 313 -0.01545
11/8/2016 20:56 313 -0.0199
11/8/2016 21:01 313 -0.0195
11/8/2016 21:06 313 -0.0178
11/8/2016 21:11 313 -0.019
11/8/2016 21:16 313 -0.0182
11/8/2016 21:21 313 -0.01805
11/8/2016 21:26 313 -0.01845
11/8/2016 21:31 313 -0.018
11/8/2016 21:36 313 -0.01645
11/8/2016 21:41 313 -0.0161
11/8/2016 21:46 313 -0.0163
11/8/2016 21:51 313 -0.0157
11/8/2016 21:56 313 -0.0152
11/8/2016 22:01 313 -0.01885
11/8/2016 22:06 313 -0.01865
11/8/2016 22:11 313 -0.0191
11/8/2016 22:16 313 -0.02055
11/8/2016 22:21 313 -0.023
11/8/2016 22:26 313 -0.0216
11/8/2016 22:31 313 -0.0174
11/8/2016 22:36 313 -0.0206
11/8/2016 22:41 313 -0.0196
11/8/2016 22:46 313 -0.0185
11/8/2016 22:51 313 -0.02025
11/8/2016 22:56 313 -0.0187
11/8/2016 23:01 313 -0.0197
11/8/2016 23:06 313 -0.01915
11/8/2016 23:11 313 -0.0192
11/8/2016 23:16 313 -0.01875
11/8/2016 23:21 313 -0.0168
11/8/2016 23:26 313 -0.01535
11/8/2016 23:31 313 -0.01515
11/8/2016 23:36 313 -0.0156
11/8/2016 23:41 313 -0.01725
11/8/2016 23:46 313 -0.0175
11/8/2016 23:51 313 -0.0183
11/8/2016 23:56 313 -0.01815
11/9/2016 0:01  314 -0.02115
11/9/2016 0:06  314 -0.01925
11/9/2016 0:11  314 -0.01605
11/9/2016 0:16  314 -0.01725
11/9/2016 0:21  314 -0.01875
11/9/2016 0:26  314 -0.01695
11/9/2016 0:31  314 -0.01585
11/9/2016 0:36  314 -0.0156
11/9/2016 0:41  314 -0.0158
11/9/2016 0:46  314 -0.01735
11/9/2016 0:51  314 -0.02115
11/9/2016 0:56  314 -0.0203
11/9/2016 1:01  314 -0.01595
11/9/2016 1:06  314 -0.0162
11/9/2016 1:11  314 -0.01845
11/9/2016 1:16  314 -0.01935
11/9/2016 1:21  314 -0.01705
11/9/2016 1:26  314 -0.01725
11/9/2016 1:31  314 -0.0183
11/9/2016 1:36  314 -0.01585
11/9/2016 1:41  314 -0.01665
11/9/2016 1:46  314 -0.0179
11/9/2016 1:51  314 -0.02015
11/9/2016 1:56  314 -0.01765
11/9/2016 2:01  314 -0.016
11/9/2016 2:06  314 -0.01575
11/9/2016 2:11  314 -0.01795
11/9/2016 2:16  314 -0.0155
11/9/2016 2:21  314 -0.01745
11/9/2016 2:26  314 -0.0203
11/9/2016 2:31  314 -0.0185
11/9/2016 2:36  314 -0.0186
11/9/2016 2:41  314 -0.01935
11/9/2016 2:46  314 -0.0184
11/9/2016 2:51  314 -0.01735
11/9/2016 2:56  314 -0.01695
11/9/2016 3:01  314 -0.01775
11/9/2016 3:06  314 -0.019
11/9/2016 3:11  314 -0.0167
11/9/2016 3:16  314 -0.015
11/9/2016 3:21  314 -0.01565
11/9/2016 3:26  314 -0.0153
11/9/2016 3:31  314 -0.0167
11/9/2016 3:36  314 -0.0172
11/9/2016 3:41  314 -0.0183
11/9/2016 3:46  314 -0.0197
11/9/2016 3:51  314 -0.01745
11/9/2016 3:56  314 -0.019
11/9/2016 4:01  314 -0.0172
11/9/2016 4:06  314 -0.0192
11/9/2016 4:11  314 -0.018
11/9/2016 4:16  314 -0.016
11/9/2016 4:21  314 -0.01565
11/9/2016 4:26  314 -0.01495
11/9/2016 4:31  314 -0.0141
11/9/2016 4:36  314 -0.0165
11/9/2016 4:41  314 -0.0181
11/9/2016 4:46  314 -0.0142
11/9/2016 4:51  314 -0.014
11/9/2016 4:56  314 -0.0154
11/9/2016 5:01  314 -0.01815
11/9/2016 5:06  314 -0.01695
11/9/2016 5:11  314 -0.01535
11/9/2016 5:16  314 -0.0173
11/9/2016 5:21  314 -0.0168
11/9/2016 5:26  314 -0.01705
11/9/2016 5:31  314 -0.0131
11/9/2016 5:36  314 -0.01255
11/9/2016 5:41  314 -0.011
11/9/2016 5:46  314 -0.0074
11/9/2016 5:51  314 -0.0033
11/9/2016 5:56  314 0.0092
11/9/2016 6:01  314 0.02835
11/9/2016 6:06  314 0.05945
11/9/2016 6:11  314 0.11275
11/9/2016 6:16  314 0.19305
11/9/2016 6:21  314 0.29155
11/9/2016 6:26  314 0.41715
11/9/2016 6:31  314 0.5569
11/9/2016 6:36  314 0.7058
11/9/2016 6:41  314 0.85515
11/9/2016 6:46  314 1.0122
11/9/2016 6:51  314 1.17105
11/9/2016 6:56  314 1.3468
11/9/2016 7:01  314 1.533
11/9/2016 7:06  314 1.72655
11/9/2016 7:11  314 1.8999
11/9/2016 7:16  314 2.0892
11/9/2016 7:21  314 2.27335
11/9/2016 7:26  314 2.45275
11/9/2016 7:31  314 2.6254
11/9/2016 7:36  314 2.80495
11/9/2016 7:41  314 2.9698
11/9/2016 7:46  314 3.14485
11/9/2016 7:51  314 3.33695
11/9/2016 7:56  314 3.5185
11/9/2016 8:01  314 3.72455
11/9/2016 8:06  314 3.91035
11/9/2016 8:11  314 4.0785
11/9/2016 8:16  314 4.2559
11/9/2016 8:21  314 4.4217
11/9/2016 8:26  314 4.5722
11/9/2016 8:31  314 4.7556
11/9/2016 8:36  314 4.9501
11/9/2016 8:41  314 5.11165
11/9/2016 8:46  314 5.2733
11/9/2016 8:51  314 5.4304
11/9/2016 8:56  314 5.56685
11/9/2016 9:01  314 5.703
11/9/2016 9:06  314 5.8769
11/9/2016 9:11  314 6.01635
11/9/2016 9:16  314 6.111
11/9/2016 9:21  314 6.24235
11/9/2016 9:26  314 6.3809
11/9/2016 9:31  314 6.5062
11/9/2016 9:36  314 6.64785
11/9/2016 9:41  314 6.75385
11/9/2016 9:46  314 6.84935
11/9/2016 9:51  314 6.93285
11/9/2016 9:56  314 7.02905
11/9/2016 10:01 314 7.11505
11/9/2016 10:06 314 7.2036
11/9/2016 10:11 314 7.2851
11/9/2016 10:16 314 7.33835
11/9/2016 10:21 314 7.44855
11/9/2016 10:26 314 7.4837
11/9/2016 10:31 314 7.53375
11/9/2016 10:36 314 7.62295
11/9/2016 10:41 314 7.66075
11/9/2016 10:46 314 7.68485
11/9/2016 10:51 314 7.7384
11/9/2016 10:56 314 7.7615
11/9/2016 11:01 314 7.82885
11/9/2016 11:06 314 7.8675
11/9/2016 11:11 314 7.91915
11/9/2016 11:16 314 7.94695
11/9/2016 11:21 314 7.93695
11/9/2016 11:26 314 7.9442
11/9/2016 11:31 314 7.9382
11/9/2016 11:36 314 7.9218
11/9/2016 11:41 314 7.92835
11/9/2016 11:46 314 7.9046
11/9/2016 11:51 314 7.8732
11/9/2016 11:56 314 7.83255
11/9/2016 12:01 314 7.803
11/9/2016 12:06 314 7.7647
11/9/2016 12:11 314 7.7232
11/9/2016 12:16 314 7.6825
11/9/2016 12:21 314 7.6342
11/9/2016 12:26 314 7.5411
11/9/2016 12:31 314 7.45375
11/9/2016 12:36 314 7.38675
11/9/2016 12:41 314 7.18185
11/9/2016 12:46 314 7.13925
11/9/2016 12:51 314 7.135
11/9/2016 12:56 314 6.98295
11/9/2016 13:01 314 6.89455
11/9/2016 13:06 314 6.8586
11/9/2016 13:11 314 6.7578
11/9/2016 13:16 314 6.65955
11/9/2016 13:21 314 6.57115
11/9/2016 13:26 314 6.442
11/9/2016 13:31 314 6.2897
11/9/2016 13:36 314 6.1718
11/9/2016 13:41 314 6.0275
11/9/2016 13:46 314 5.88025
11/9/2016 13:51 314 5.73785
11/9/2016 13:56 314 5.5934
11/9/2016 14:01 314 5.4494
11/9/2016 14:06 314 5.1863
11/9/2016 14:11 314 4.98255
11/9/2016 14:16 314 4.8496
11/9/2016 14:21 314 4.8176
11/9/2016 14:26 314 4.6013
11/9/2016 14:31 314 4.2561
11/9/2016 14:36 314 3.96345
11/9/2016 14:41 314 3.9824
11/9/2016 14:46 314 3.9432
11/9/2016 14:51 314 3.7544
11/9/2016 14:56 314 3.4839
11/9/2016 15:01 314 2.7597
11/9/2016 15:06 314 2.4419
11/9/2016 15:11 314 2.64675
11/9/2016 15:16 314 2.45525
11/9/2016 15:21 314 2.4179
11/9/2016 15:26 314 2.3876
11/9/2016 15:31 314 2.23465
11/9/2016 15:36 314 2.07505
11/9/2016 15:41 314 1.79335
11/9/2016 15:46 314 1.415
11/9/2016 15:51 314 1.25875
11/9/2016 15:56 314 0.99305
11/9/2016 16:01 314 0.716
11/9/2016 16:06 314 0.51725
11/9/2016 16:11 314 0.43155
11/9/2016 16:16 314 0.42175
11/9/2016 16:21 314 0.52755
11/9/2016 16:26 314 0.4067
11/9/2016 16:31 314 0.2853
11/9/2016 16:36 314 0.18875
11/9/2016 16:41 314 0.1121
11/9/2016 16:46 314 0.0422
11/9/2016 16:51 314 0.0087
11/9/2016 16:56 314 -0.01395
11/9/2016 17:01 314 -0.0253
11/9/2016 17:06 314 -0.03095
11/9/2016 17:11 314 -0.03115
11/9/2016 17:16 314 -0.0322
11/9/2016 17:21 314 -0.03055
11/9/2016 17:26 314 -0.02585
11/9/2016 17:31 314 -0.02525
11/9/2016 17:36 314 -0.0207
11/9/2016 17:41 314 -0.01985
11/9/2016 17:46 314 -0.0202
11/9/2016 17:51 314 -0.0216
11/9/2016 17:56 314 -0.02065
11/9/2016 18:01 314 -0.02215
11/9/2016 18:06 314 -0.02005
11/9/2016 18:11 314 -0.017
11/9/2016 18:16 314 -0.01985
11/9/2016 18:21 314 -0.02015
11/9/2016 18:26 314 -0.02005
11/9/2016 18:31 314 -0.01875
11/9/2016 18:36 314 -0.019
11/9/2016 18:41 314 -0.01875
11/9/2016 18:46 314 -0.0196
11/9/2016 18:51 314 -0.0123
11/9/2016 18:56 314 -0.01185
11/9/2016 19:01 314 -0.01485
11/9/2016 19:06 314 -0.0187
11/9/2016 19:11 314 -0.02015
11/9/2016 19:16 314 -0.01935
11/9/2016 19:21 314 -0.0197
11/9/2016 19:26 314 -0.01885
11/9/2016 19:31 314 -0.0218
11/9/2016 19:36 314 -0.0169
11/9/2016 19:41 314 -0.01205
11/9/2016 19:46 314 -0.01245
11/9/2016 19:51 314 -0.0112
11/9/2016 19:56 314 -0.01655
11/9/2016 20:01 314 -0.0185
11/9/2016 20:06 314 -0.0204
11/9/2016 20:11 314 -0.0227
11/9/2016 20:16 314 -0.02115
11/9/2016 20:21 314 -0.01345
11/9/2016 20:26 314 -0.0135
11/9/2016 20:31 314 -0.0191
11/9/2016 20:36 314 -0.0172
11/9/2016 20:41 314 -0.0136
11/9/2016 20:46 314 -0.0129
11/9/2016 20:51 314 -0.0176
11/9/2016 20:56 314 -0.01285
11/9/2016 21:01 314 -0.0138
11/9/2016 21:06 314 -0.0179
11/9/2016 21:11 314 -0.0193
11/9/2016 21:16 314 -0.02365
11/9/2016 21:21 314 -0.02045
11/9/2016 21:26 314 -0.0218
11/9/2016 21:31 314 -0.0215
11/9/2016 21:36 314 -0.02105
11/9/2016 21:41 314 -0.0184
11/9/2016 21:46 314 -0.01795
11/9/2016 21:51 314 -0.01945
11/9/2016 21:56 314 -0.01865
11/9/2016 22:01 314 -0.01425
11/9/2016 22:06 314 -0.0125
11/9/2016 22:11 314 -0.0093
11/9/2016 22:16 314 -0.01355
11/9/2016 22:21 314 -0.01235
11/9/2016 22:26 314 -0.01205
11/9/2016 22:31 314 -0.01225
11/9/2016 22:36 314 -0.0138
11/9/2016 22:41 314 -0.01255
11/9/2016 22:46 314 -0.01655
11/9/2016 22:51 314 -0.01695
11/9/2016 22:56 314 -0.01605
11/9/2016 23:01 314 -0.018
11/9/2016 23:06 314 -0.01165
11/9/2016 23:11 314 -0.00995
11/9/2016 23:16 314 -0.0181
11/9/2016 23:21 314 -0.0137
11/9/2016 23:26 314 -0.014
11/9/2016 23:31 314 -0.02185
11/9/2016 23:36 314 -0.0238
11/9/2016 23:41 314 -0.02165
11/9/2016 23:46 314 -0.02095
11/9/2016 23:51 314 -0.01925
11/9/2016 23:56 314 -0.0201
```

Comment: Please make this reproducible, otherwise it will be very difficult for people to help you.

Comment: I added data for the first few days. Is there anything else that would be useful? It's my first time posting here, so any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Post your data by pasting in the output of `dput()`. That way, we'll have a data frame with the exact same structure as your actual data frame. For example, to post the first 40 rows of your data, paste in the output of `dput(original_data[1:40,])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This looks like a timezone issue. When you convert the dates to POSIXct, the default timezone is your local timezone. But when you run `date_format()` inside `ggplot`, the dates are converted to GMT before plotting, so times are all shifted by the difference between GMT and your local timezone. To get the correct hours plotted, you can either explicitly set the desired timezone within `date_format` or you can explicitly set the timezone to GMT when you convert `Date` to POSIXct.

---

Before working on the ggplot code, let's look at your data. Below, I've started with your data before the conversion of `Date` to POSIXct:

```
head(original_data)
str(original_data)
```

> ```
>             Date DOY Reference
> 1 11/7/2016 0:01 312  -0.01370
> 2 11/7/2016 0:06 312  -0.01525
> 3 11/7/2016 0:11 312  -0.01325
> 4 11/7/2016 0:16 312  -0.01235
> 5 11/7/2016 0:21 312  -0.01190
> 6 11/7/2016 0:26 312  -0.01120
>
> 'data.frame': 864 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ Date     : chr  "11/7/2016 0:01" "11/7/2016 0:06" "11/7/2016 0:11" "11/7/2016 0:16" ...
> $ DOY      : int  312 312 312 312 312 312 312 312 312 312 ...
> $ Reference: num  -0.0137 -0.0152 -0.0132 -0.0123 -0.0119 ...
> ```

Now let's convert `Date` to POSIXct in two different ways: First, without setting the timezone and then with setting the timezone to GMT. Note that `Date1` is in my local timezone (U.S. Pacific), while `Date2` is in GMT, though the literal time strings are the same:

```
original_data$Date1 <- as.POSIXct(x = original_data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
original_data$Date2 <- as.POSIXct(x = original_data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")

head(original_data$Date1)
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-11-07 00:01:00 PST" "2016-11-07 00:06:00 PST" "2016-11-07 00:11:00 PST" "2016-11-07 00:16:00 PST"
> [5] "2016-11-07 00:21:00 PST" "2016-11-07 00:26:00 PST"
> ```

```
head(original_data$Date2)
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-11-07 00:01:00 GMT" "2016-11-07 00:06:00 GMT" "2016-11-07 00:11:00 GMT" "2016-11-07 00:16:00 GMT"
> [5] "2016-11-07 00:21:00 GMT" "2016-11-07 00:26:00 GMT"
> ```

Here's the code for the `date_format` function. Note the default `tz` (timezone) setting is `UTC`, which is the same as `GMT`. So `date_format` is shifting time values from the your data's timezone to GMT:

```
date_format
```

> ```
> function (format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC") 
> {
>     function(x) format(x, format, tz = tz)
> }
> ```

Now for `ggplot`: First we'll work with `Date1`. In the examples below, note that when we use the default date formatting, the hours are correct. However, when we use `scale_x_datetime` without specifying a timezone, it looks like ggplot is shifting from my local timezone (U.S. Pacific) to GMT, which is 8 hours later. However, when I specify the "America/Los_Angeles" timezone in `date_format()`, I get the desired hour values.

```
# Create plot with Date1, but without scale_x_datetime
p = ggplot(original_data, aes(Date1, Reference)) +
  facet_wrap(~ DOY, scales="free_x") + 
  xlab("Time (hours)") + 
  geom_point() +     
  ylab(expression(Radiation ~ (W ~ m^{-2}))) +
  ggtitle("Calibration Plots") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"), 
        title = element_text(size=9, face = "bold"))

p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours") + 
  ggtitle("Default date formatting") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=9, angle=-90, , vjust=0.5))
p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", labels=date_format("%H")) + 
  ggtitle('date_format("%H")')
p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", labels=date_format("%H", tz="America/Los_Angeles")) +
  ggtitle('date_format("%H", tz="America/Los_Angeles")')
```

[image]

On the other hand, if we use `Date2`, which is already set to the GMT timezone, then we don't need to specify the timezone within `date_format()`:

```
# Create plot with Date2, but without scale_x_datetime
p = ggplot(original_data, aes(Date2, Reference)) +
  facet_wrap(~ DOY, scales="free_x") + 
  xlab("Time (hours)") + 
  geom_point() +     
  ylab(expression(Radiation ~ (W ~ m^{-2}))) +
  ggtitle("Calibration Plots") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"), 
        title = element_text(size=9, face = "bold"))

p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours") + 
  ggtitle("Default date formatting") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=9, angle=-90, , vjust=0.5))
p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", labels=date_format("%H")) + 
  ggtitle('date_format("%H")')
p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 hours", labels=date_format("%H", tz="GMT")) +
  ggtitle('date_format("%H", tz="GMT")')
```

[image]

Comment: Great thorough answer. Also note that " `scale_*_datetime()` now supports time zones. It will use the timezone attached to the varaible by default, but can be overridden with the `timezone` argument." (From NEWS.)

Comment: Thank you! This was impressively clear and thorough. I really appreciate you taking the time to walk me through why this was happening and the options for fixing it.

Comment: @Axeman, thanks for letting me know as I wasn't aware of that (guess I'm not keeping up with the latest ggplot2 news as well as I should). Isaac, you're welcome!